# How to handle SoftReference listeners after it has been GC'd?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, soft-references

So I've been playing with this new library and I noticed that one of the listeners that I must provide context with is binded through a `SoftReference`.

My activity does a lot of heavy lifting even when it is put through the background which may cause this `SoftReference` to get GC'd...which isn't good because i'm listening for some event that could happen any time.

What's the proper way to handle this in the event that this listener gets GC'd?